# How to attach Bucket to Google Compute Engine VM on Startup?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, bucket

I would like to, on startup, copy contents of my bucket to the VM with the [Container Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/). When the server shuts down I'd like to save the changes back to the bucket.

I've tried making a startup script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
toolbox
gsutil cp -r gs://my-bucket/
```

However, this causes the VM to fail on startup despite this script working if I run it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a reasonable solution. My script has changed to

```
#! /bin/bash
toolbox --bind=/home/username/bucket-folder:/my-bucket <<< "gsutil cp -r /my-bucket/* gs://my-bucket"
```

So what happens is we need to call toolbox --bind to bind a folder from the server to the toolbox container. Then we use <<< to pass the whole command to the container when it starts up so we copy to the newly bound directory so it goes back to the server.

Now when I bound the directory in my docker container, everything is there!

Comment: Do you know that you can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried:

```
#! /bin/bash
gsutil cp -r gs://my-bucket /
```

And it worked for me. What is the `toolbox` command that you are executing previously?

Anyway you can see what is failing in the [Serial Port Output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output).

**EDIT**: In the [Container Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits) this does not work as this OS does not have the gsutil package `preinstalled`. Refer to @DanBaba [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774729/7757976).

Comment: It doesn't work in the Container Optimized OS, gsutil gives you the unknown command error. Running the script in the question ran into the issue that you need to be in the toolbox command to execute the gsutil command. So the answer seemed to be to pass the command TO the toolbox command. That is if I understand it myself. I'm editing the question to include the fact that detail I missed when asking originally.

Comment: @DanBaba, your are right, in the Container Optimized OS you don't have the gsutil package installed by default so the solution you provided seems to be very good.